# Adding GDELT to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

I've been trying to add GDELT events data to BigQuery with no success so far..
I use the link below in my attmpets; clicking view dataset >> create table >> add arbitrary table name >> create table and then I get this error:

You are missing permissions and may need to talk to your administrator. Original error message: Failed to create table: Access Denied: Dataset gdelt-bq:gdeltv2: Permission bigquery.tables.create denied on dataset gdelt-bq:gdeltv2 (or it may not exist).

I tried changing my roles to admin and data editor but I still get the same error above.

Anyone who can help?

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/the-gdelt-project/gdelt-2-events?filter=solution-type:dataset&id=a41570ce-2ee5-444c-80d8-1dd6ee6602ad&walkthrough_tutorial_id=java_gae_quickstart
_gae_quickstart

Comment: No, you cannot modify this project by adding there your table. Please go to BigQuery and click on the blue text on the top left "+ ADD DATA" next the explorer window. Then "Star a project by name" and enter `gdelt-bq` and click on the star button. The project will be added to your view and you can search for the table to query.

Answer (score 0):

GDELT is a public dataset where it can't be edited or you can't create a table without the administrator's permissions. Even if you tried changing your roles to `Admin and Data Editor`, the changes you made are within your project only. The ones who handle GDELT dataset are the ones who will grant you the permissions, but I don't think it is possible since GDELT is for public use.

I highly recommend the procedure written in the comment above for you to be able to view and explore GDELT database.